# Android - setOnClickListener() on dynamic list of Filenames

Tags: android, file, dynamic, mp3, onclicklistener

I have a simple function that lists all filenames of a specific folder "MP3"as TextViews .. I now want to make some further action with them, but i have no clue how to do that with a OnCLickListener()

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private File root;
private ArrayList<File> fileList = new ArrayList<File>();
private LinearLayout mp3List;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mp3List = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mp3List);
    root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/MP3");
    getfile(root);
    for (int i = 0; i < fileList.size(); i++) {
        final TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setText(fileList.get(i).getName());
        textView.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.i("MainActivity", " WHAT IS THIS ITEM'S ID?? ");
            }
        });


        System.out.println(fileList.get(i).getName());            
        mp3List.addView(textView);
    }
}


public ArrayList<File> getfile(File dir) {
    File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();
    if (listFile != null && listFile.length > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {
            if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {
                fileList.add(listFile[i]);
                getfile(listFile[i]);
            } else {
                if (listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".mp3")) {
                    fileList.add(listFile[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return fileList;
}
```

}

Can someone tell me, how do I get the Filename of the TextView tat was generated for the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some possible solutions:

- If you just want to get the name of the file, in your listener do `textView.getText()`
- You can add a complex object to any view using the method [`View#setTag(Object)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag(java.lang.Object)), and retrieve this complex object by using [`View#getTag():Object`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getTag()).

In any case, the code I am looking at is not optimized since Android is not thought to create views dynamically, at least this is not the normal way to create lists. Have a look to `ListView` or the new equivalent `RecyclerView`, both allow to recycle the views and scroll over them.